# Server side pagination of laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having some trouble implementing **server side pagination** in Laravel 5.
Do you have any idea please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this one

```php
//in controller
$users = \App\User::paginate(15)
    return view('your desired view file name', compact('users'));


// in view
      <div class="text-center text-muted" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing {{$users->firstItem()}} to {{$users->lastItem()}} of {{$users->total()}} entries</div>
        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;" >
            <p></p>
            {!! with(new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter($users))->render()!!}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you do somrthing like following

```
    $users = \App\User::paginate(15)
    return view('template.file', compact('users'));
```

and in View file you put following

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
           <td> {{ $user->name }} </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! $users->appends(\Input::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Last line renders pagination links.

Comment: laravel error --Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry I made small mistake. 'all()' returns collection and collection class does not have paginate method. you just need   `App/User::paginate(15)`